# printing slowly (Simulate typing)

Tags: python

I am trying to make a textual game in python. All goes well however, I would like to make a function that will allow me to print something to the terminal, but in a fashion hat looks like typing.

Currently I have:

```
def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        print letter,
        time.sleep(.1)

print_slow("junk")
```

The output is:

```
j u n k
```

Is there a way to get rid of the spaces between the letters?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Python 2.x you can use [`sys.stdout.write`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) instead of `print`:

```
for letter in str:
    sys.stdout.write(letter)
    time.sleep(.1)
```

In Python 3.x you can set the optional argument `end` to the empty string:

```
print(letter, end='')
```

Comment: err, doesn't the buffer needs a `sys.stdout.flush()` ? that's the heart of the issue when not printing line termination chars.

Answer (score 17):

This is my "type like a real person" function:

```
import sys,time,random

typing_speed = 50 #wpm
def slow_type(t):
    for l in t:
        sys.stdout.write(l)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(random.random()*10.0/typing_speed)
    print ''
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)

print_slow("Type whatever you want here")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import sys,time

def sprint(str):
   for c in str + '\n':
     sys.stdout.write(c)
     sys.stdout.flush()
     time.sleep(3./90)

sprint('hello world')
```