# Python: Printing letters one by one in Command Prompt

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, printing, cmd

Recently I've picked up  Python 3.4 programming and I read this other question regarding how to  [printing slowly (Simulate typing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099422/print-slowly-in-python-simulate-typing), and used a similar def in my code.

```
import time

def type(str):
     for letter in str:
        print(letter, end='')
        time.sleep(0.02)
    print("\n")

type("This sentence is typed.")
```

It all worked fine in IDLE, but once I tried running it using Windows Command prompt, CMD waits the time it took IDLE to type it (half a second in this case) and then spits it out as if it had been printed.

I figured the time.sleep statement was broken one way or another, although

```
print("One")
time.sleep(2)
print("Two")
```

worked just fine.

Is there any way of printing one letter at a time with a short interval between the letters, or is it simply not possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try forcing a flush on `stdout` after each character. The problem is that `stdout` is normally buffered until either a newline, EOF or a certain number of bytes have been output.

```
import time
import sys

def type(str):
    for letter in str:
        print(letter, end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.02)
    print("\n")

type("This sentence is typed.")
```

Alternately, in Python3, as @PeterWood mentioned, you can change your print so that it auto-flushes.

```
        print(letter, end='', flush=True)
```

Comment: Since Python 3.3 you can say `print(letter, flush=True)`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print).

Comment: @PeterWood, Thanks for the note. I will edit the answer.