# Why is my program printing to only one line instead of a seperate line?

Tags: python

so i'm using this snippet of code:

```
def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
    print letter,
    time.sleep(.1)
```

from this link on SO: [printing slowly (Simulate typing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099422/print-slowly-in-python-simulate-typing?newreg=117d11c5570c472ebfce62191fb8d55f)
and if fits my needs. However, my code so far is this:

```
import time
import random
import sys
def print_slow(str):
   for letter in str:
   print letter,
   time.sleep(.5)
print_slow("MEME QUEST!")
time.sleep(.5)
print_slow("BY XXX XXXXX")
```

But when I run this code, it prints both snippets of code on the same line. Is there any way to put them on seperate lines?

EDIT: Adding an extra print to the print_slow function worked, thank you.

Comment: Remove the comma from `print letter,`. The comma literally tells it to suppress the newline and continue printing on the same line

Comment: @CoryKramer: that's the point, they *want* that comma there to print things 'slowly' on a line. What is missing is a plain `print` to write the newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a newline; normally `print` outputs that, but not if you add a `,` comma at the end.

You could insert an extra blank `print` between calls to `print_slow()` to write one:

```
print_slow("MEME QUEST!")
print
time.sleep(.5)
print_slow("BY XXX XXXXX")
print
```

You could just add that extra `print` statement to the function:

```
def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        print letter,
        time.sleep(.1)
    print
```

A blank `print` writes the missing newline.

Alternatively, add a `\n` newline character to the text you print:

```
print_slow("MEME QUEST!\n")
time.sleep(.5)
print_slow("BY XXX XXXXX\n")
```

but take into account the same .1 second delay applies to writing the newline too.

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply add a newline character

```
print_slow("MEME QUEST!\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

The comma after your

```
print letter,
```

statement is suppressing it from printing a new line.

Try

```
import time

def print_slow(string):
        for letter in string:
            print letter,
            time.sleep(.1)
        print '\n'

print_slow("hello")
print_slow("world")
```

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to implement this but this should resolve your problem.