# printing every thing slowly (Simulate typing)

Tags: python, python-3.x, simulation, simulator

[[printing slowly (Simulate typing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099422/printing-slowly-simulate-typing/10390877#10390877[1])

I got my answer from the link above but it only works when you put the string as a **parameter** when calling function.

I want the code to print slowly every time when I use `print()`.

is it possible?

Comment: why can't you call that function instead?

Comment: cause I don't want to call that function every time I print sth. I'm going to use print several times.

Comment: But you want to call print() every time you print sth...  just do find/replace... call that function prnt and you'll even save yourself a character

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you define aliases for imported modules in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706595/can-you-define-aliases-for-imported-modules-in-python)

Comment: You can probably import it as an alias to `print` but I wouldn't want to override a built in keyword, you'd be better off just using the method when you want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using the stdout version as below.

```
import sys, time

def print(s):
    for letter in s:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        time.sleep(.1)

print("Foo")
```

Comment: did you just name your function print and it worked?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it like this, however, I think it's not a good idea:

```
import time
def dprint(string):
   for letter in string:
        __builtins__.print(letter,end = '', flush=True)
        time.sleep(.1)
   __builtins__.print("")

print = dprint

print("something")
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me that `__builtins__` is a thing..  I guess you'd never use it because no-one would be silly enough to over-ride a built-in function... right?

Comment: one of the reasons, that `print()` became a function in python3 was, that you can override it if you ever need to, though I agree, that it is not such a good idea in most cases.

Comment: cool really solved my problem but how can python output lists, dictionaries, and other stuff slowly?

Comment: @iammgt you can do it like this: print(str([1,2,3,4,5]))

Answer (score 0):

Changing the default behaviour of `print()` is not recommended and was only introduced for purpose of porting Python 2 programs easily. Moreover overloading the print function without a special parameter will make the default functionality of `print()` moot.

Create another function with adds a delay to the prints. Also remember that you cannot use `print()` because it appends a new line. You’ll have to you `sys.stdout.write()`

So a basic function would look like:

```
def typrint(x):
    for i in len(x):
        sys.stdout.write(x[i])
        sleep(0.05)
    sys.stdout.write(“\n”)
```

Check this [article](https://snarky.ca/why-print-became-a-function-in-python-3/) to see why Python updated `print()` to a function

Comment: with python3 you can use `print` with `end=""`  and don't have to use `sys.stdout.write()`

Comment: can you explain how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this as the solution for the problem,

```
import sys,time
def delay(str):
   for i in str:
       sys.stdout.write(i)
       sys.stdout.flush()
       time.sleep(0.04)
```

Note: You need to add in every print statement or here "delay" statement "\n".