# Local variable 'ushieldcount' referenced before the assignment

Tags: python, reference, local-variables

I'm just beginning to learn coding, so I'm just looking for hints at this point. The code is as followed:

```
import math
import random
import time
import sys
health = 100
ophealth = 80
player = False
opponent = False
# Took a code from sebastian ( def print_slow(str) part )
# Author: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1366738/sebastian
# Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099422/printing-slowly-simulate-typing  
def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
def healthbar(health):
    return str(health)
def healthbar(ophealth):
    return str(ophealth)
def damaged(health):
    return health - 20
    health = health - 20
def damaged(ophealth):
    return ophealth - 20
    ophealth = ophealth - 20
gender = str(input('Hello! what gender are you? male or female?\n'))
name = str(input('Hm... whats your name?\n'))
age = str(input('and how old are you?\n'))
print_slow('alright! your registerd as ' + name + ", " + age + " years old, and " + gender + "!!\n")
ushieldhitcount = 0
mshieldhitcount = 0
def play():
    if ushieldhitcount >= 1 0:
        print('your shield broke! when your shield broke, tiny part of metal got in your eye and the monster killed you! YOU LOST')
        exit()
    if mshieldhitcount >= 10:
        print('the monsters shield broke and a piece got in the monsters eye, and you killed the monster while it was blinded!!! YOU WIN')
        exit()
    monster = random.choice(['att','def'])
    player = input('welcome! enter to continue\n')
    print_slow('You ran into a monster!\n')
    print('att to attack\n')
    print('def to defend\n')
    print('you have ' + str(healthbar(health)) + ' and the monster has ' + str(healthbar(ophealth)) + '\n') 
    player = input('run to attempt to run\n')
    if player == 'att' and monster == 'att':
        print_slow('the monster also chose to att! your swords clashed into each other!')
    if player == 'att' and monster == 'def':
        print_slow('you attacked! but they shielded! dealing 0 damage\n')
        print('you have ' + str(healthbar(health)) + ' and the monster has ' + str(health(ophealth))+'\n')
        mshieldhitcount = mshieldhitcount + 1
    if player == 'def' and monster == 'att':
        print_slow('you defended! and the monster attacked! dealing you 0 health')
        ushieldhitcount = ushieldhitcount + 1
    if player == 'def' and monster == 'def':
        print_slow('LMAO, you guys both defended dealing each other NOTHING')
        print('you have ' + str(healthbar(health)) + ' and the monster has ' + str(healthbar(ophealth)) + '\n') 
    
print(play())
```

On compile, it reports

```py
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ushieldhitcount' referenced before assignment.
```

I tried many things to fix this but I don't really know how. Can someone help me out? please do not comment the answer, and give a hint if you could. I want to get hints and do it on my own so I can improve. Thank you very much for reading all this!

Comment: Have you read any tutorials about scope in Python? That is what the problem is here.

Comment: This is an issue with scope. Also,m you have defined some functions twice. Look at `heathbar` and `damaged`.

Answer (score 0):

after  line `def play():`
put

`global ushieldhitcount`

also

`global mshieldhitcount`

also remove one of the duplicated functions

and also another thing after `return` line, no commands executed

Comment: I have a duplicated function? I don't see it

Comment: those `helthbar` and `damaged`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the variables `ushieldhitcount` and `mshieldhitcount`

are outside the function `play()`

to use a variable that is defined outside a function,we use the keyword `global`

try this:

```
def play():
global ushieldhitcount
global mshieldhitcount 
if ushieldhitcount >= 10:
    print('your shield broke! when your shield broke, tiny part of metal got in your eye and the monster killed you! YOU LOST')
    return
if mshieldhitcount >= 10:
    print('the monsters shield broke and a piece got in the monsters eye, and you killed the monster while it was blinded!!! YOU WIN')
    return
```

with the rest of your code...

if you have any more problems let me know!